# Dúvida Layout Web

Tags: php, google-maps, front-end

Galera, preciso fazer um layout como deste protótipo anexado na postagem, onde são fotos associadas com uma localização enviadas por um dispositivo móvel, a minha duvida é o seguinte, quais ferramentas devo utilizar para o desenvolvimento? pretendo fazer o back-end utilizando php para buscar as coordenadas do banco que serão utilizadas no mapa, mas no front-end não sei se existe alguma biblioteca ou framework para agilizar o desenvolvimento, pois não tenho muita experiência com desenvolvimento web.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Hum, então, esta pergunta se qualifica como baseada em opiniões.
Você precisa ter uma idéia do que precisa ser feito e já ter tentado algo para solicitar uma resposta...

Comment: Olá @MarceloAymone, irei editar ela então para ser mais especifico, obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Já fiz um aplicativo batsante semelhante aqui na empresa, não utlilizei nenhuma ferramenta para agilizar o desenvolvimento, até porque não encontrei nenhuma. Usei CSS3, HTML5, LESS e JavaScript para o front e PHP para back.

Um problema que tivemos foi quanto ao mapa, utilizamos inicialmente o Google Maps mas os usuários eram muitos e acabamos com a API grátis, infelizmente tivemos que migrar para o OpenLayers 3 para sair da limitação do Google Maps.

Framework frontend existe o [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Comment: Obrigado pela dica!

Answer (score 0):

Isso vai depender bastante da sua necessidade. Utilizar um framework como Bootstrap no inicio iria levar um tempo pela questão de aprendizado. Em contrapartida iria te ajudar para tornar sua página responsiva, e na diagramação dos elementos na tela.

Como seu conhecimento em front-end é baixo a faixa de aprendizado irá ser a mesma.

Leve em consideração se é um sistema legado, pois, se for tente não sair muito do padrão.